# Matthew 12:40 : Jesus resurrection day of the week

Tags: matthew, gospels

Are there any references to the day of the week when Jesus was resurrected besides Matthew 12:40 and following conclusion that it was Saturday night or Sunday early morning?

Matthew 12:40 King James Version (KJV)

40 For as Jonas was three days and three nights in the whale's belly; so shall the Son of man be three days and three nights in the heart of the earth.

Comment: The expression *a day and a night* (or *n days and n nights*) is a Hebrew [idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom), explained in the [Talmud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud) as (also) including partial days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Jewish Sabbath day starts at sundown on Friday and lasts till sundown on Saturday, the seventh day of the week.  The first day of the week starts at sundown on Saturday and lasts till sundown on Sunday.  Our calendar gives the first day of the week as Sunday (starting after midnight).  With that in mind, we can go straight to the gospel of John for confirmation that Jesus was resurrected in the early hours of Sunday.  Remember, the Apostle John was an eyewitness of Jesus’ crucifixion and death.  This is what his gospel says:

> Now on the first day of the week Mary Magdalene came to the tomb early, while it was still dark, and saw that the stone had been taken away from the tomb. (John 20:1).
>
> On the evening of that day, the first day of the week, the doors being locked where the disciples were for fear of the Jews, Jesus came and stood among them and said to them, “Peace be with you.” (John 20:19).

All four gospel accounts are most specific about it being early on the Sunday morning when it was discovered that the tomb was empty:

> Now after the Sabbath, toward the dawn of the first day of the week, Mary Magdalene and the other Mary went to see the tomb (Matthew 28:1).
>
> And very early on the first day of the week, when the sun had risen, they went to the tomb (Mark 16:2).
>
> But on the first day of the week, at early dawn, they went to the tomb, taking the spices they had prepared (Luke 24:1).

Jesus' first appearance took place early on Sunday morning:

> Now when he rose early on the first day of the week, he appeared first to Mary Magdalene (Mark 16:9).